# Tomcat ServletContext cannot load class

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, wicket

I have the need to communicate between two web applications. Both are tomcat projects. I want to avoid using http requests to communicate. After doing some research I discovered there is a ServletContext object which is meant to handle this.

I was following the guide on http://blog.imaginea.com/cross-context-communication-between-web-applications/ and decided to try this in my own quickstarts.

I made sure my tomcat server had its crossContext set to true.

```
<Context crossContext="true">
```

I created two wicket quickstarts one named bar and one named foo. The idea was that I could call a function in foo from bar.

Here is the code in bar

```
String methodName = getRequest().getParameter("PARAM_METHOD");
    ServletContext srcServletContext = ((WebApplication)WebApplication.get()).getServletContext();
    ServletContext targetServletContext = srcServletContext.getContext("/foo");

    ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    try
    {
        Object object = targetServletContext.getAttribute("org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.CONTEXT.foo");

        ClassLoader targetServiceClassLoader = targetServletContext.getClass().getClassLoader();

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(targetServiceClassLoader);

        // Causes a ClassNotFoundException
        Class<?> classBarService = (Class<?>)targetServiceClassLoader.loadClass("com.foo.SomeUtil");

        Method getTextMethod = object.getClass().getMethod("getText", String.class);

        Object someUtil = getTextMethod.invoke(object, "someUtil");

        Method targetMethod = classBarService.getMethod(methodName, (Class[])null);

        Object responseFromTextMethod = targetMethod.invoke(someUtil, (Object[])null);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        text += e.toString();
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currentClassLoader);
    }
```

foo has a class named SomeUtil in the package com.foo.
But when I try to load the class after changing the class loader I am getting a "ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.SomeUtil". I can't really tell what I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if have CrossContext set to `true`, the ClassLoader of the calling class needs to have access to the class that it is trying to load.

Try to deploy the jar(s) containing the classes to both web applications.

quote from the tutorial:

> Solution-1: If we could externalize the custom data type classes which are accessed by multiple web applications (here accessed by ‘Foo’ and ‘Bar’) to a different library and place it inside the commons library location of the web container (In case of tomcat, it is <TOMCAT_HOME>\lib),

Either you deploy the jar to both webapps, or to commons/lib, but AFAIK, newer versions of tomcat don't provide commons/lib anymore by default

Comment: I guess I was thinking that was just for handling custom data types. In the example above they were talking about simple data types that are native to java. In my example I am just working with string.

Comment: You're not just working with Strings. You try to call a method on the class `com.foo.SomeUtil` - a class that the ClassLoader cannot find. Hence the ClassNotFoundException

Comment: I have now included the jar but I am getting the 

            ClassNotFoundException with the Class<?> classBarService = (Class<?>)targetServiceClassLoader.loadClass("com.foo.SomeUtil");

call before I am trying to call a method on that class.

Comment: Going to accept this answer. I think the key was putting the jars in both projects. In the end I was unable to get this working and decided to use sockets instead to pass information between the apps.

Comment: Well I see that even Tomcat 9 has a /lib folder and according to the doc, https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html if you put a JAR file there, those classes should be loaded only once by class loader and therefore have static fields which are reusable. Needs some testing enough

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace

```
ClassLoader targetServiceClassLoader = targetServletContext.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

with

```
ClassLoader targetServiceClassLoader = object.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

like it was proposed in the tutorial?

Comment: Yes I have the code posted in the question. Looks like you typo'd you have the same code in both lines.

Comment: No, there's no typo. One says **targetServletContext** .getClass()... and the other **object** .getClass()...

Comment: I'll give that a shot today and see what happens. Sorry the mobile app cut off some of your text so I didn't see that part.